# What is the proper Content-Security-Policy meta tag definition to allow any request?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've swapped over to the new Cordova plugins that are now hosted on npm and the whitelist plugin generated "No Content-Security-Policy" meta tag errors so I thought I'd try one of the documented meta tags that sounded like it would allow any request to get through. This is what I use from the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Using that meta tag, I call a third party API to fetch a javascript resource and that is the error that I get now:

`Refused to load the script https://example.net/path/control.ashx?querystring=value because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; script-src 'self' https://domain.net">
```

To allow script requests to "https://domain.net".  Documentation on this can be [found here](http://content-security-policy.com/).  You may also want to look at connect-src if pulling data from the network too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this meta tag and it wouldn't load my own javascript resources, unfortunately.

Comment: You could try opening script-src up to * and see if that works for you then dial it back to just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it globally allow any requests, this solution ended up working for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Omitting `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` from `script-src` would not work for me.